# numerical issues causing the difference in outputs of two programs?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have two codes that theoretically should return the exact same output. However, this does not happen. The issue is that the two codes handle very small numbers (doubles) to the order of 1e-100 or so. I suspect that there could be some numerical issues which are related to that, and lead to the two outputs being different even though they should be theoretically the same.

Does it indeed make sense that handling numbers on the order of 1e-100 cause such problems? I don't mind the difference in output, if I could safely assume that the source is numerical issues. Does anyone have a good source/reference that talks about issues that come up with stability of algorithms when they handle numbers in such order?

Thanks.

Comment: are you able to test the scenario by getting it to output more reasonable results?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a good source/reference that talks about issues that come up with stability of algorithms when they handle numbers in such order?

The first reference that comes to mind is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It covers floating-point maths in general.

As far as numerical stability is concerned, the best references probably depend on the numerical algorithm in question. Two wide-ranging works that come to mind are:

- [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) by Press et al;
- [Matrix Computations](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Matrix_Computations.html?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC) by Golub and Van Loan.

Comment: "What every Computer scientist..." Excellent reference. Really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily the small numbers that are causing the problem.

How do you check whether the outputs are the "exact same"?

I would check equality with tolerance. You may consider the floating point numbers `x` and `y` equal if either `fabs(x-y) < 1.0e-6` or `fabs(x-y) < fabs(x)*1.0e-6` holds.

Usually, there is a HUGE difference between the two algorithms if there are numerical issues. Often, a small change in the input may result in extreme changes in the output, if the algorithm suffers from numerical issues.

What makes you think that there are "numerical issues"?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, change your algorithm to use Kahan Summation (aka compensated summation). From Wikipedia:

```
function KahanSum(input)
    var sum = 0.0
    var c = 0.0          //A running compensation for lost low-order bits.
    for i = 1 to input.length do
        y = input[i] - c    //So far, so good: c is zero.
        t = sum + y         //Alas, sum is big, y small, so low-order digits of y are lost.
        c = (t - sum) - y   //(t - sum) recovers the high-order part of y; subtracting y recovers -(low part of y)
        sum = t             //Algebraically, c should always be zero. Beware eagerly optimising compilers!
        //Next time around, the lost low part will be added to y in a fresh attempt.
    return sum
```

This works by keeping a second running total of the cumulative error, similar to the Bresenham line drawing algorithm. The end result is that you get precision that is nearly double the data type's advertised precision.

Another technique I use is to sort my numbers from small to large (by manitude, ignoring sign) and add or subtract the small numbers first, then the larger ones. This has the virtue that if you add and subtract the same value multiple times, such numbers may cancel exactly and can be removed from the list.